# creepy characters shows in my script

Tags: php

I've a php script work's well in the localhost, but when I launched it every page has these characters in the beginning.

`ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ï»¿`

any idea what are these ?

Answer (score 3):

`ï»¿` is the Byte Order Mark (BOM) of the Unicode Standard. Specifically it is the hex bytes `EF BB BF`, which form the UTF-8 representation of the BOM, misinterpreted as ISO 8859/1 text instead of UTF-8.

Probably what it means is that you are using a text editor that is saving files in UTF-8 with the BOM, when it should be saving without the BOM. It could be PHP files that have the BOM, in which case they'd appear as literal text on your page.

The Unicode Consortium's FAQ on the Byte Order Mark is at http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM

Comment: I'm using `coda` for mac. how i can access these bytes and remove them ?

Comment: @Othman although I don't use mac, there is a simple solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498409/removing-bit-order-mark-from-php-files-in-coda)

Answer (score 0):

They're misencodings of the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that your text editor has placed in all the files.

```
>>> u'ï»¿'.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
u'\ufeff'
```